# HTML/CSS and svg

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm making an SVG diagram in HTML line in the code below. I have a an SVG line, I have applied `strokedashed` array to divide the line with gaps. However I want to divide the SVG line into dots separated by gaps (meaning circles). Is it possible?

```html
<div style="height: 50%; width: 50%; margin-top: 40px; background: yellow; padding: 10px;">
    <svg width="50%" height= 50%; >
      <line class="line" x1="10" y1="0" x2="10" y2="100%" style="stroke:blue;stroke-width:20;" />  
    </svg>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: For dots use `stroke-linecap="round"`. Please keep in mind that the strokes must be **very** short to create a round dot. Otherwise you will get a line with rounded caps. Also the gaps between strokes must be wider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a nice jsfiddle for this.

`stroke-linecap` seems to be the trick.

https://jsfiddle.net/eliranmal/hsfxS/